# using ufw to block outgoing traffic to website

Tags: firewall, ufw

I want to block traffic to a specific domain e.g. mysite.com. I tried blocking the ip address of the site but it does not work:

```
ufw deny from 0.0.0.0 to ip_address_of_site
```

I am still able to acess the website, even after a reboot.

Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It will be:

```
sudo ufw deny out from any to _ipaddress_
```

Comment: Can you do it with a domain name? The best would be like this  > sudo ufw deny out from any to *.domain.com

Comment: @user3021729 AFAIK no. UFW creates iptables chains like ufw-user-output and ufw-user-input where you can put more complicated rules, but domain names probably won't work because iptables/nftables loads before dns and can't resolve names. Probably it will fail to load rules (but maybe something changed)

Comment: This didn't work for me with an Nginx website. After executing this, I can't ping that ip, but I can still reach to my website which is in that ip.

Comment: @Sahin can't tell anything without seeing configuration. Maybe you should ask a question describing your problem.

Comment: For me, it works fairly reliably. I just do `dig domain` to put whatever is in the A record, and it works well. (Not sure if that'll cause problems for cases where it's going through Cloudflare and such, though.)